# PostgreSQL: Select field value and update with next value from second table

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE t_a
(
  a_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  str VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE t_b
(
  b_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  a_id_fk INTEGER REFERENCES (t_a(a_id),
)
```

Using the above tables, I want to `SELECT a_id_fk FROM t_b WHERE b_id = 1` and then update `a_id_fk` with the next `a_id` in the sequence, but if I'm at the end of the available `a_id`'s I cycle back to the first one. All this with multiple people querying/updating that specific row from `t_b`.

If it helps, the scenario I'm working on is multiple sites share a common list of words, but as each user for each sites grabs a word that sites index within the word list is moved to the next word until it hits the end then it loops back to the beginning.

Is there a way to do this in a single query? If not, what would be the best way to handle this? I can handle most of the logic, it's looping back when I run out of ids that has me stumped.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a question?

Comment: You want to update t_b.a_id_fk ? What should the new value be?

Comment: The new value would be the next t_a.a_id when ordered by a_id unless there wasn't one, in that case it would start back at the beginning. It's the starting back at the beginning that's not so easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something complicated like

```
UPDATE t_b
    SET a_id_fk = COALESCE(
        (SELECT MIN(a_id) FROM t_a WHERE a_id > t_b.a_id_fk),
        (SELECT MIN(a_id) FROM t_a))
    WHERE b_id = :b_id
```

but if I was given a requirement like that I'd probably maintain an auxiliary table that maps an a_id to the next a_id in the cycle...

Comment: I've never thought about using a query within a COALESCE, but I guess that would work. How would I structure an auxiliary table to handle this and would it be able to maintain a separate index for each entry in `t_b`?

Answer (score 0):

This one is a bit more elegant (IMHO) than @pdw's solution:

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE t_a
( a_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
, str VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE t_b
( b_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
, a_id_fk INTEGER REFERENCES t_a(a_id)
);

INSERT INTO t_a(str)
SELECT 'Str_' || gs::text
FROM generate_series(1,10) gs
        ;
INSERT into t_b(a_id_fk)
SELECT a_id FROM t_a
ORDER BY a_id
        ;

-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
WITH src AS (
        SELECT a_id AS a_id
        , min(a_id) OVER (order BY a_id) AS frst
        , lead(a_id) OVER (order BY a_id) AS nxt
        FROM t_a
        )
UPDATE t_b dst
SET a_id_fk = COALESCE(src.nxt, src.frst)
FROM src
WHERE dst.a_id_fk = src.a_id
AND dst.b_id IN ( 3, 10)
        ;

SELECT * FROM t_b
ORDER BY b_id
        ;
```

---

Result:

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 10
INSERT 0 10
UPDATE 2
 b_id | a_id_fk 
------+---------
    1 |       1
    2 |       2
    3 |       4
    4 |       4
    5 |       5
    6 |       6
    7 |       7
    8 |       8
    9 |       9
   10 |       1
(10 rows)
```